# Using scripts_for_layout in plugin helper method

Tags: cakephp, plugins

i writing my menu plugin helper (similar to cakemenu)
and i want to you js and css related to my plugin
with in scripts_for_layout

how to add them to plugin helper method?

```
class AdminmenuHelper extends AppHelper {
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Javascript');
function show() {
$output = '
<ul>
    <li><a href="/users/dashboard"><img src="/img/admin/icons/home.png" border="0" />;02=0O</a></li>    
    <li><a href="/admin/products/"><img src="/img/admin/icons/document.png" border="0" />@>4C:F8O</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/categories/"><img src="/img/admin/icons/document.png" border="0" />0B53>@88</a></li>
    <li><a href="/users/logout"><img src="/img/admin/icons/door-open-in.png" border="0" />KE>4</a></li>
</ul>
';
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your helper, you can add one of these 2 methods

**#1**

```
function beforeRender() {
    $html = new HtmlHelper();
    $html->script('custom', false);
}
```

**#2**

```
function beforeRender() {
    $view =& ClassRegistry::getObject('view');
    $view->addScript('<script type="tex/javscript" src="' . Router::url('/js/custom.js') . '"></script>');
}
```

**#2** is lighter because it does not need to instantiate a new helper, but you have to write te entire javascript tag. It’s up to you to choose which one you like more.